# Vertx http server use only one instance of worker thread

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x

I have a simple http vertx based server with the following code:

```
public class JdbcVertx extends AbstractVerticle{

    private static int cnt;
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {        
        this.vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(request -> {
                    JdbcVertx.cnt++;
                    System.out.println("Request "+JdbcVertx.cnt+" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    this.vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
                        System.out.println("Blocking: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        final String resp = this.dbcall();
                        future.complete(resp);
                    }, asyncResp -> {
                        request.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html");
                        if (asyncResp.succeeded()) {
                            request.response().end(asyncResp.result().toString());
                        } else {
                            request.response().end("ERROR");
                        }
                    });
                }).listen(8080);
    }

    private String dbcall(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("From sleep: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JdbcVertx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();   
    }
```

From official docs i have read that default worker pool size is 20. But this is my output

```
 Request 1 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Blocking: vert.x-worker-thread-0
Request 2 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Request 3 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Request 4 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Request 5 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
From sleep: vert.x-worker-thread-0
Blocking: vert.x-worker-thread-0
Request 6 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
From sleep: vert.x-worker-thread-0
```

I have two questions:

1)Why my verticle use only one worker thread?

2) From output

```
Request 1 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Blocking: vert.x-worker-thread-0
Request 2 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Request 3 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Request 4 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
Request 5 vert.x-eventloop-thread-0
```

server get first request , put it to the worker thread and then get 2,3,4,5 requests.Why it works in this way? Maybe responses are put to the queue for worker pool?

Thank in advance

BTW i deploy using console (`vertx run JdbcVertx.java`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an excellent question.
`executeBlocking()` actually has three parameters `blockingHandler`, `ordered` and `resultHandler`
When you call it with only two arguments, `ordered` is defaults to `true`
For that reasons all requests within the same context will receive the same worker thread - they're executed sequentially.
Set it to `false` to see that all worker threads start working.
You can also check this example of mine:
https://github.com/AlexeySoshin/VertxAnswers/blob/master/src/main/java/clientServer/ClientWithExecuteBlocking.java

And here you can see that it's actually being put on the queue:
https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/impl/ContextImpl.java#L280

Comment: Thank for response , now its work , but why vertx are designed at this way . I mean we use execute blocking for concurrent execution, what is the reason to make it sequential ?

Comment: `executeBlocking` is worst way to be concurrent. It's the complete opposite - to be as not concurrent and backward compatible as possible. Think if you're writing regular Java code, you wouldn't expect that `dbcall(); dbcall();` (that is, two calls to same function) will execute concurrently, right? And that's exactly what `executeBlocking` is trying to do - be synchronous.

Comment: but how to avoid concurrent resource modifications, is it any alternative to be used for thread safety and to be more responsive for requests?

Comment: As with any other program. Either use something that solved concurrent modification for you (Atomics, Concurrent, etc) or introduce finely grained lock mechanism.